# Issue in MySql SSl connection

Tags: mysql, linux, ssl, centos

I have enabled SSL on mysql 5.5.34 [CentOS release 6.4 (Final)]

we have two users for linux : "root" and "admin"

and 2 users for mysql : "root" and "mysqladmin"

I also have created one mysql user called sslclient using below command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO sslclient@'%' REQUIRE SSL; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO sslclient@'localhost' REQUIRE SSL;
```

I had to do "chown mysql.mysql /etc/mysqlssl/*" and "chmod 440 /etc/mysqlssl/*" to enable SSL

Made sure that SSL is enabled by doing "show variables like '%ssl%'"

```
+---------------+-------------------------------+ 
| Variable_name | Value | 
+---------------+-------------------------------+ 
| have_openssl | YES | 
| have_ssl | YES | 
| ssl_ca | /etc/mysqlssl/ca-cert.pem | 
| ssl_capath | | 
| ssl_cert | /etc/mysqlssl/server-cert.pem | 
| ssl_cipher | | 
| ssl_key | /etc/mysqlssl/server-key.pem | 
+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

We are facing two issues:

1) When I try to connect mysql using (from linux "admin" user)

```
mysql -u sslclient --ssl-ca=/etc/mysqlssl/ca-cert.pem
```

gives me error : *"ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: Failed to set ciphers to use"*

2) I can connect mysql (from linux "root" user) only using mysql "root" user, not using any other user say "mysqladmin" or "sslclient", i.e.

`"mysql -u mysqladmin"` gives me below error

*"Access denied for user 'mysqladmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"*

Would there be any relation between both the issues?

What could be the cause and/or solution for above issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to [provide an SSL cipher option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-options.html#option_general_ssl-cipher):

> If no cipher in the list is supported, SSL connections will not work.

This documentation refers to the command-line program, but you can also set it in your config file:

```
ssl_cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA
```

You can specify a colon-separated list of ciphers to use, and find out which ciphers are supported by your MySQL install by running `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher_list';` at a mysql prompt.